# How to generate x12 file by hand

Tags: edi, x12, hipaa

I work for a small healthcare company. We use a simple browser-based gui to create our healthcare claims. Recently our number of claims has grown. To make things easier, we'd like to be able to batch bill our claims now. We only do 1 type of procedure (this requirement will not change for the foreseeable future). I need to generate an 837I file for said procedure.

Any resources to learn about building an edi file as well as any walkthroughs about how I can do this for one procedure? I'm not looking for an already created solution. I'm also not looking to buy anything. I'm not looking to create a full x12 parsing tool.

We already have a solution for receiving acknowledgements and remittance advice. However, we don't have a simple way to batch upload unless we create 837 formatted files. This is only for one procedure so I'm looking to do this myself and learn as I go along.

Comment: Good luck. I've done this, and it ain't pretty. You're going to at least need to buy the implementation guide, and find an extremely patient trading partner willing to do extensive testing while you figure out the complexities and nuances. With that being said, your question (asking for resources to point you in the right direction) is off-topic here, as is clearly stated in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - see the section with the numbered list on that page.

Comment: You can create an EDI document from scratch using EDI Notepad from Liaison.  That can at least get you creating a document.  After you get the syntax correct, then you can work on creating your own custom code to generate the file to look exactly like that.  EDI Notepad is free, downloadable from Liaison.

Comment: changes of making a correctx12 file by hand are about 0.01%. Using a tool like Andrew suggest cna get you up to 1% correct messages. Only 99 of 100 x12 transactuions will be in error! Please realise that the reason why your edi-partner want to do edi is to eliminate errors....

Comment: I implemented an 834 x12 file generator by hand for insurance claims and it was an enjoyable experience. As @KenWhite stated, documentation is crucial from the given partner you are working with. It took me about a week to build, but as I built it I realized that everyone supporting the given x12 format will have slightly different variances; i.e. random character restraints, padding with zero requirements, custom delimiters, you name it. As for resources, this image [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19398-01/820-1275/agdaw/index.html) really helped me grasp the looping structure.

Comment: Yep I agree with @KenWhite not simple as you think, I had experience with 270 Request that is half of the section in 837 but so complex. I think Mirth Connect (https://www.mirth.com/) will help you about creating and parsing part.